# Can´t open a zip file downloaded from my website

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, download

I need to download a zip file from my node js express app. This is the code I use on the server to send the file to the browser:

```
  app.get('/files', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const file  = await service.getFile('http://localhost:8080/myapp/test.zip');
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test1.zip');
            res.send(file);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
        }
    });
```

The code of the web client (React) is:

```
import {Button} from 'semantic-ui-react';

const axios = require('axios');
const FileDownload = require('js-file-download');

const handleClick = async () => {
    const {data} = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/files',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'XXXXXX'},
        responseType: 'stream'
    });
    FileDownload(data, 'file.zip');
}

export default () => <div><Button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Download file</Button></div>
```

The zip is downloaded correctly, I can see that the size is actually the size of the source file from the server, however when I try to unzip on a Mac, I get: Error(1), Operation not permitted.

Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that it is really a zip file? Because `test.pdf` indicates that it is a pdf file and not a zip file

Comment: sorry about that, actually yes, it is a zip file, the url does not matter here, it was only for testing purposes

Comment: And the md5 sum of both the downloaded and the original file are the same?

Comment: Operation not permitted means that you don't have permission. You are probably on Linux. Move the file to another folder where you have "write" permission or chmod the zip.